# Error: retrieving gpg key timed out

Tags: 14.04, gnupg, add-apt-repository

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa 
       The most current stable version of Git for Ubuntu.
       For release candidates, go to    https://launchpad.net/~git-ore/+archive/candidate .
       Plus d’info : https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
       Appuyez sur [ENTRÉE] pour continuer ou sur Ctrl-c pour annuler    l'ajout.
       gpg: le trousseau local « /tmp/tmphiju7w7q/pubring.gpg » a été créé
-->>   Error: retrieving gpg key timed out.
       gpg: /tmp/tmphiju7w7q/trustdb.gpg : base de confiance créée
       gpg: clef A1715D88E1DF1F24 : clef publique « Launchpad PPA for Ubuntu    Git Maintainers » importée
       gpg: Quantité totale traitée : 1
       gpg:               importées : 1
       OK
```

" EN :
I tried to install one app in **LINUX UBUNTU**, *But this error block me* .
So please help me  =} .

" FR :
J'essayais d'installer une application dans **LINUX UBUNTU**, *Mais cette erreur me bloque* . Alors aidez-moi s'il vous plaît =} .

```
 "AR :
حاولت تنزيل برنامج على لينوكس اوبانتو ، لكن هذه المشكلة منعنتي من التقدم  
                                           -  اسف لم اجد مصطلحا اقرب -
                                           =}     لذا ساعدوني ارجوكم -
```