# add-apt-repository fails due to gpg key timeout

Tags: 18.04, apt, gnupg

I am running a [Mail-in-a-Box](https://mailinabox.email/) server on Ubuntu 18.04. As part of the setup/update script, it attempts to execute the command `add-apt-repository -y ppa:certbot/certbot`. This fails with the following error message:

```
FAILED: add-apt-repository -y ppa:certbot/certbot
-----------------------------------------
Error: retrieving gpg key timed out.
-----------------------------------------
```

When I try to run the command manually, I get the following error:

```
Error: retrieving gpg key timed out.
```

---

### Things I have already tried

*I have tried all of the following and none of them resolved my issue. If there*
*was an obvious way to undo what I tried, I undid it before trying the next*
*thing.*

#### Reboot

I rebooted the server with `sudo reboot`.

#### apt-get --allow-releaseinfo-change

[This person](https://discourse.mailinabox.email/t/solved-upgrade-0-41-to-0-42-fails-add-apt-rep-certbot-certbot/5349)
had a similar problem and solved it with
`sudo apt-get --allow-releaseinfo-change update`.

#### Let's Encrypt down

[It has been suggested](https://discourse.mailinabox.email/t/cant-install-0-40-as-lets-encrypts-pgp-key-times-out-solved/4347/2)
([twice](https://discourse.mailinabox.email/t/error-retrieving-gpg-key-timed-out/7353/2))
that Let's Encrypt may be
down. However, I have tried running the command at various times, their
[status dashboard](https://letsencrypt.status.io/) doesn't indicate any major
issues and it runs fine on a different Ubuntu 18.04 machine I set up for
testing.

#### Wrong nameserver

[This user](https://discourse.mailinabox.email/t/miab-not-loading-any-more/5824/6) had a similar issue, which he solved by editing his `/etc/resolv.conf` file.
My file had the contents `nameserver 127.0.0.1`. I know that Mail-in-a-Box can
also function as a nameserver, so I assume it is fine. For thoroughness' sake
I changed it to `nameserver 8.8.8.8`, but this didn't fix the problem.

#### apt autoclean & autoremove

[A commenter suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1129548/retrieving-gpg-key-timed-out-what-does-this-mean#comment1874470_1129548)
running `sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt autoremove`.

#### Switch keyserver

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61901064/5687894) suggests editing the
`~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` file to use a different keyserver:
`keyserver keys.openpgp.org`

[This other user](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/error-retrieving-gpg-key-timed-out/94861/3)
does what appears to be the same thing but inline. I tried
`sudo add-apt-repository -k hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 -y ppa:certbot/certbot`
and
`sudo add-apt-repository -k hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 -y ppa:certbot/certbot`.

[This third user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110594) apparently tries to
change the keyserver and port in a different way. I tried his command
`gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 94558F59`.

[A fourth person](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/223398) suggested the
following two commands:
`gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 94558F59` and
`gpg --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 94558F59`.

#### Disable firewall

[This person](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60213283/5687894) tried disabling
their firewall before running the command. So did I with `sudo ufw disable`.

[Someone else](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/error-retrieving-gpg-key-timed-out/94861/2)
thought unblocking port 11371 might work. I tried `sudo ufw allow 11371`.

I also don't believe that an ISP-firewall is causing issues. I am running a VPS
from Vultr and my testing-machine (on which it works) is also hosted by them.

---

### Miscellaneous

I believe a fresh install of the operating system would alleviate this issue.
However, I would prefer not to do this if at all possible.

I was unsure, whether this question would better fit the *ask ubuntu* or the *server fault* Stackexchange so I took the liberty of posting it on both sites.

Comment: Did you try manually adding the PPA?

Comment: If you mean running `add-apt-repository -y ppa:certbot/certbot` from the console - then yes, I did.

Comment: I mean manually adding the PPA by creating `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/certbot-ubuntu-certbot-bionic.list`. I installed using the tool, so I also have `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/certbot-ubuntu-certbot-bionic.list.save`.

Comment: It also appears there is a debug option with `add-apt-repository -m`.

Comment: Here is a straightforward manual add post: https://blog.zackad.dev/en/2017/08/17/add-ppa-simple-way.html

Comment: I tried running it with -m. Maybe you can glean more from the results than me: https://pastebin.com/56rf5knX

Comment: Is there anything in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`?

Comment: @Paul, yes there is, strangely. It contains `certbot-ubuntu-certbot-bionic.list  certbot-ubuntu-certbot-bionic.list.save`. Both of the files contain this:`deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu bionic main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu bionic main`

Comment: Okay, so it looks like the script stopped at the install certbot PPA because IIRC right after that it installs duplicity PPA. On the manual steps I should have looked a little more because it's the steps after adding the URL that matter. If this is a VPS, my recommendation is spool up a new instance and just try to install the certbot PPA and see what happens.

Comment: I already did. The 'different Ubuntu 18.04 machine I set up for testing' from the *Let's Encrypt down* section is a Vultr VPS. If I run `add-apt-repository -y ppa:certbot/certbot` there, it works fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123620/discussion-between-paul-and-sebastian-hietsch).